# Displacement of a cantilever beam

Tags: calculus, power-series, physics

A student asked me for help on the following problem:

> Suppose that the bending moment $M(x)$ can be modeled via the vertical displacement $w(x)$ of a beam where $E$ and $I$ are constant. $$
>   \frac{M(x)}{EI} = -\frac{w''(x)}{[1 + w'(x)^2]^\frac{3}{2}}
> $$
>   Write $\frac{M(x)}{EI}$ as a power series in terms of $w'$.

---

My first thought was to write $$
  -\frac{w''(x)}{[1 + w'(x)^2]^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[-\frac{w'(x)}{\sqrt{1 + w'(x)^2}}\right],
$$ but I'm not sure how to write this as a power series either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with the student and we were able to figure it out.

Simply factor and use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series): $$
  -w''(x)\frac{1}{[1 + w'(x)^2]^\frac{3}{2}}
  = -w''(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-3/2}{n} w'(x)^{2n}.
$$